# flutter slider value from state

Tags: flutter, build, slider, state

I'm new to `Flutter` and have 2 questions.

I'm trying to use a `Slider` by setting initial value from the `State` which I can get later after build.

But my issue is that every time I move the `Slider`, the `Builder` set the same value from the `State` and the `Slider` doesn't get updated and also doesn't move.

Second question is similar to first one. As you can see under `onChangeEnd()` method I'm using an another `Slider` in a `BottomSheet`, with an endvalue ( getting from the first Slider). But again I can't move the 2nd `Slider`. I guess the reason is it's also refreshing after build.

It would be amazing if you can tell how to fix this and do it properly.

Thanks

```
class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailPage State createState() => _DetailPage State();
}

class _DetailPage State extends State<DetailPage > {
  double _currentSliderValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, AppState>(
        converter: (store) => store.state,
        builder: (context, state) {
          _currentSliderValue = state.progress.toDouble();
          return Scaffold(
            body: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Slider(
                          value: _currentSliderValue,
                          min: 0,
                          max: 100,
                          divisions: 100,
                          label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
                          onChanged: (double newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              _currentSliderValue = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          onChangeEnd: (double endValue) {
                            ModalHelper.showBottomModal(
                              context,
                              _currentSliderValue.toString() + " " + endValue.toString(),
                              Slider(
                                value: endValue,
                                min: 0,
                                max: 100,
                                divisions: 100,
                                label: endValue.round().toString(),
                                onChanged: (double newValue) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    endValue = newValue;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

SOLUTION:

first question:
I added simple flag on set state of first slider to not re set _currentSliderValue value after rebuild.

second question:
made showBottomModal statefull solve that problem.

Comment: Could you show full code of the ModalHelper

Comment: ModalHelper.showBottomModal is just calling bottomsheet, I can view slider on bottomsheet sucesfully. Like I said, my problem is about using endvalue of main slider on there, which results slider not updating.

Comment: That's creating the problem. I have added the sliders without the bottom sheet and it's working fine.

Comment: Ok I ll check that, but what do you think about first part of my question. Getting value of first slider from           _currentSliderValue = state.progress.toDouble(); resulting slider not updating because it's in build

Comment: The first slider is also connected with second. When it's getting error in the 2nd slider it's causing problem also in the first.

Comment: But I remove onChanged part complately and first problem still occurs

Comment: I added as an answer the code I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the `bottomSheet` and changed the code a bit, it works now.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'arrow.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool loaded = false;
  double _currentSliderValue = 0;
  double _currentSliderValue2 = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) => {
          //Do more things
          setState(() {
            loaded = true;
          })
        });
  }

  ThemeData getTheme(BuildContext context) {
    // I wanna be able to call MediaQuery.of(contex) here
    return ThemeData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Slider(
                        value: _currentSliderValue,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        divisions: 100,
                        label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
                        onChanged: (double newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _currentSliderValue = newValue;
                          });
                        },
                        onChangeEnd: (double endValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _currentSliderValue2=endValue;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Slider(
                        value: _currentSliderValue2,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        divisions: 100,
                        label: _currentSliderValue2.round().toString(),
                        onChanged: (double newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _currentSliderValue2 = newValue;
                          });
                        },

                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }


}
```

Comment: This solves my second problem. Thank you very much. But my main problem is about setting _currentSliderValue initial value in builder. The initial value I need to set _currentSliderValue is in redux state and I'm doing it in builder because I can only reach redux state in builder. (as far as I know). This line in builder -> _currentSliderValue = state.progress.toDouble(); causing me problem. To summerise I dont want first slider initial value 0, I need to change that initial value.

Comment: You can retrieve and set data in build also by this: setState(() {
                            _currentSliderValue = reduxValue;
                          });

Comment: If It worked. Please set it as correct answer. It would be helpful for others.